# How to use options with GCC pragma optimize? (eg. max-peeled-insns)

Tags: gcc, pragma

I am aware that I can enable or disable certain optimizations via function attributes (or globally via a pragma) in GCC using the following syntax:

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("peel-loops")
```

This is equivalent to passing `-fpeel-loops` at the command line for the file (assuming this is the first line in the file). But what if I need to *configure* loop peeling equivalently to passing `--param max-peeled-insns=200` at the command line? I tried a few things, none of which work:

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("max-peeled-insns=200")
#pragma GCC optimize ("param max-peeled-insns=200")
#pragma GCC optimize ("--param max-peeled-insns=200")
```

How can I do this from within the source code?